# Create unique key list from dictionary array in one-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a code like below. Although it works, I want to know more compact implementation. Is it possible to implement this code as one or two liners?

```
all_keys = []
dic_list = [{'apple': None, 'banana': None}, {'grape': 1, 'apple':None}]
for d in dic_list:
    for k in d.keys():
        if k not in all_keys: all_keys.append(k)
print(all_keys) # ['apple', 'banana', 'grape'] all unique keys
```

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, please mark the correct answer with the checkbox beside it—this benefits you, the answerer, and the community. If it hasn't been answered, what's missing?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `set.union` across the dictionaries:

```
>>> set().union(*dic_list)
{'apple', 'banana', 'grape'}
```

This approach is **much** faster than a double loop (such as `set( val for dic in dic_list for val in dic.keys()))`)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
list(set( val for dic in dic_list for val in dic.keys()))
```

Output:

```
['grape', 'apple', 'banana']
```

Comment: Its one line but its longer and much slower than it needs to be

Comment: both are good answers but this one and @aryamccarthy's answer are easier to understand, for my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set (marked by curly braces `{}`), which enforces that elements are not repeated:

```
all_keys = {k for d in dic_list for k in d.keys()}
# {'apple', 'banana', 'grape'}
```

This strategy is more efficient than looping, and the intent is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, my inference is a shorter implementation which prints the keys in sorted manner.

```
dic_list = [{'apple': None, 'banana': None}, {'grape': 1, 'apple':2}]
all_keys = sorted({k for d in dic_list for k in d.keys()})
print(all_keys)
```

We can use python's powerful List/Set/Dictionary comprehensions to achieve this with relatively fewer lines of code.

Hope this helps.